# webpack, how to manage dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, webpack

I have a module called gridstack which use the following things:

```
(function(factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery', 'lodash', 'jquery-ui/core', 'jquery-ui/widget', 'jquery-ui/mouse', 'jquery-ui/draggable',
            'jquery-ui/resizable'], factory);
    }
```

But it can't resolve the jquery-ui dependencies, how to manage that in webpack ?

If I don't use webpack I would do that:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gridstack.js/dist/gridstack.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my research, I have seen that the require('somefile.js') js function is used to add a dependency that webpack will resolve.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem using *webpack* and *npm*, do the following:

Install packages using *npm*

`npm install jquery-ui lodash gridstack --save-dev`

Create an alias in *webpack.config.js*

```
alias: {
            "lodash": "node_modules/lodash",
            "jquery-ui": "node_modules/jquery-ui",
            "gridstack": "node_modules/gridstack"
        }
```

Require the modules in your javascript/typescript/whatever file

```
require('lodash');
require('jquery-ui');
require('gridstack');
```

In order for *webpack* to recognize which files to include in your bundle, you have to require them. The alias in your config file makes sure that *webpack* knows where to actually find the files you're trying to include. Including the .js files in your *html* file does not work, especially when you're trying to combine both methods (including in *html* and including through *webpack*). This is because they can't reference to eachother when they have dependencies.